# Java - Generate random array with length given by input

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a school project of a Casino Java App using OOP and Swing for GUI. 
I have to build a slot machine which receives a number of boxes by user input and when user hits the "play" button, It needs to retrieve a random combination of fruits with the length of the input. 
For example, if user wants the slot machine to have 3 boxes, there should be a random combination of 3 fruits out of all the fruits I have in my array. 
Lets say I have 20 fruits available, I need to use only as many fruits as boxes. If user wants 5 boxes in the slot machine, I need to retrieve 5 fruit combination.
I hope i explained myself

For this project I created a Fruit enum class, and I mapped the name of the fruit with a picture of it to show it in the slot machine.

```
public enum Fruta {

    PERA("pera.png", "pera"),
    BANANA("banana.png", "banana"),
    FRUTILLA("frutilla.png", "frutilla");

    private String archivo;
    private String descripcion;

    Fruta(String archivo, String descripcion) {
        this.archivo = archivo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getArchivo() {
        return archivo;
    }

    public static Fruta obtenerPorValor(String text){
        for (Fruta f : Fruta.values()) {
            if (f.descripcion.equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
                return f;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In my controller class, 'Casino', I built the 'play' method:

```
public Fruta[] jugar(TicketView ticket,MaquinaTragamonedasView maquinaView) {
    MaquinaTragamonedas maquina = buscarMaquina(maquinaView.getIdMaquina());
    if(ticket.getCredito() >= maquina.getCosteJugada() && ticket != null) {
        Fruta[] combinacion = maquina.jugar();
        return combinacion;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Play method inside my MaquinaTragamonedas (slot machine) class:

```
public Fruta[] jugar () {

    if(verificarRecaudacionMinima()){
        mostrarMensaje();
    };
    return generarCombinacion(cantidadCasillas);

}
```

This is how i generate the random combination of fruits inside the Slot machine class:

```
public Fruta[] generarCombinacion(int cantidadCasillas) {
    Random random = new Random();
    Fruta[] combinacion = {Fruta.values()[random.nextInt(Fruta.values().length)], Fruta.values()[random.nextInt(Fruta.values().length)], Fruta.values()[random.nextInt(Fruta.values().length)]};
    return combinacion;
}
```

As you can see I need the numer of boxes (cantidadCasillas) to retrieve the combination, but cant get my head to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This code will take the parameter into account:

```java
public Fruta[] generarCombinacion(int cantidadCasillas) {
    Random random = new Random();
    Fruta[] combinacion = new Fruta[cantidadCasillas];
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadCasillas; i++) {
        combinacion[i] = Fruta.values()[random.nextInt(cantidadCasillas)];
    }
    return combinacion;
}
```

There are multiple ways in java to create an array. In your code you chose the way to directly instantiate the array with values, there you had no chance of making its size depend on the parameter.

`new Fruta[cantidadCasillas]` creates an array of the length of variable `cantidadCasillas` and the for-loop sets the values one-by-one.